# MixedReality-WebRTC: Cannot apply remote description: Value does not fall within expected range

Tags: unity-game-engine, webrtc, hololens, mrtk

I'm building a small client that allows real-time communication between a Hololens (1 and 2), and a web browser (node.js/socket-io - testing with Chrome 104.0.5112.102).

My node webrtc client works fine when I'm connecting browser-browser, but I'm running into an issue trying to apply the remote description using the MixedReality-WebRTC.Unity library.

Unity Version 2019.4.36f1

The application fails when calling - specifically it fails on the `HandleConnectionMessageAsync` call with the error specified in the title.  Even more specifically, it is failing on the `Peer.SetRemoteDescriptionAsync` call that happens within the MR-WebRTC `PeerConnection` script.

```
PeerConnection.HandleConnectionMessageAsync(sdpOffer).ContinueWith(_ =>
                    {
                        Debug.Log("creating answer");
                        // If the remote description was successfully applied then immediately send
                        // back an answer to the remote peer to acccept the f.
                        _nativePeer.CreateAnswer();

                    }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion | TaskContinuationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
```

Here's the sdp message being generated by my Node.js client:

```
sdpOffer 

content: 
v=0
o=- 8927256642058541481 3 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 2 3
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS RtP0zfpJEUfvzSkEP45Dh4OhSixmm03qz16t
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 63 103 104 9 0 8 106 105 13 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:zjPC
a=ice-pwd:rCxmU70XktVR0nrlgQ+SYjTQ
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 26:9C:0C:8A:36:8E:C1:14:ED:B6:DF:C5:CD:38:71:66:1D:A4:70:16:66:91:E6:E5:24:3A:6E:B3:08:C1:99:E8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:2
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=sendrecv
a=msid:RtP0zfpJEUfvzSkEP45Dh4OhSixmm03qz16t 0b4e2cb6-0268-45d7-be7a-14df41fc3daf
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:63 red/48000/2
a=fmtp:63 111/111
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:106 CN/32000
a=rtpmap:105 CN/16000
a=rtpmap:13 CN/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
a=ssrc:2102406938 cname:KVan8CJD2J5AfWQ+
a=ssrc:2102406938 msid:RtP0zfpJEUfvzSkEP45Dh4OhSixmm03qz16t 0b4e2cb6-0268-45d7-be7a-14df41fc3daf
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 97 127 121 125 107 108 109 124 120 123 119 35 36 41 42 98 99 100 101 114 115 116 117 118
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:zjPC
a=ice-pwd:rCxmU70XktVR0nrlgQ+SYjTQ
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 26:9C:0C:8A:36:8E:C1:14:ED:B6:DF:C5:CD:38:71:66:1D:A4:70:16:66:91:E6:E5:24:3A:6E:B3:08:C1:99:E8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:3
a=extmap:14 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:2 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:13 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:3 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:5 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space
a=extmap:4 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:mid
a=extmap:10 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:rtp-stream-id
a=extmap:11 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:sdes:repaired-rtp-stream-id
a=sendrecv
a=msid:RtP0zfpJEUfvzSkEP45Dh4OhSixmm03qz16t 85428e07-74bb-4df4-ae83-482549d4095f
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:127 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:127 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:127 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:127 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack
a=rtcp-fb:127 nack pli
a=fmtp:127 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:121 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:121 apt=127
a=rtpmap:125 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:125 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:125 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:125 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack
a=rtcp-fb:125 nack pli
a=fmtp:125 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:107 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:107 apt=125
a=rtpmap:108 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:108 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:108 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:108 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack
a=rtcp-fb:108 nack pli
a=fmtp:108 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:124 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:124 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:124 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack
a=rtcp-fb:124 nack pli
a=fmtp:124 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=rtpmap:120 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:120 apt=124
a=rtpmap:123 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:123 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:123 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:123 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack
a=rtcp-fb:123 nack pli
a=fmtp:123 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:119 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:119 apt=123
a=rtpmap:35 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:35 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:35 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:35 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack
a=rtcp-fb:35 nack pli
a=fmtp:35 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=0;profile-level-id=4d001f
a=rtpmap:36 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:36 apt=35
a=rtpmap:41 AV1/90000
a=rtcp-fb:41 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:41 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:41 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack
a=rtcp-fb:41 nack pli
a=rtpmap:42 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:42 apt=41
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=fmtp:98 profile-id=0
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 profile-id=2
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:114 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:114 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:114 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:114 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack
a=rtcp-fb:114 nack pli
a=fmtp:114 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=64001f
a=rtpmap:115 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:115 apt=114
a=rtpmap:116 red/90000
a=rtpmap:117 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:117 apt=116
a=rtpmap:118 ulpfec/90000
a=ssrc-group:FID 501149046 1205188850
a=ssrc:501149046 cname:KVan8CJD2J5AfWQ+
a=ssrc:501149046 msid:RtP0zfpJEUfvzSkEP45Dh4OhSixmm03qz16t 85428e07-74bb-4df4-ae83-482549d4095f
a=ssrc:1205188850 cname:KVan8CJD2J5AfWQ+
a=ssrc:1205188850 msid:RtP0zfpJEUfvzSkEP45Dh4OhSixmm03qz16t 85428e07-74bb-4df4-ae83-482549d4095f

type:
offer
```

I'm wondering if it may be a codec mismatch since Unity/HL don't like H.264, but I can't for the life of me seem to force VP8/VP9.

The library unfortunately is deprecated - but Microsoft hasn't provided an alternative - it seems to work relatively well, though their tutorials are a bit out of date with the current version.

Any hints as to what could be behind this?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the "PreferredVideoCodec" property of PeerConnection to your desired codec.  For Example:
_peerConnection = new PeerConnection { PreferredVideoCodec = "VP8" };

Comment: Good thought, but unfortunately no luck! Same error.

Actually having the same issue only trying to transmit audio.